# Disabling same origin policy in Cordova 5.0.0

Tags: cordova, same-origin-policy, cordova-5.0.0

How can i disable same origin policy in Cordova 5.0.0? It seems to be enabled and i need to disable it for development reasons. I've tried to install crosswalk in hope of something changing but cross domain requests are still disabled. Im deploying to Android 5.1.

EDIT: I do have `cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0` and both `<access origin="*">` and a CSP meta tag with `default-src *`

Also note that this problem only happens when using a remote src like `<content src="http://remoteserver.com/app/index.html">`. Everything works fine when content src is local like `<content src="index.html">`. But i need to have a remote content src to avoid having to redeploy the app every single write-run-debug cycle on a mobile device.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you read the documentation of the [cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and about [CSP](http://content-security-policy.com/).

With cordova 3.* yoy only had to configure origin from anywhere in config.xml.

With Cordova 5 you have to add cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin in your project (automatically added for new projects), configure the plugin in config.xml and configure the CSP in your html files.

Comment: I do have the whitelist plugin configured. CSP header is set. The thing is, this all works as long as content src is set to some local file like `<content src="index.html">` but when using a remote content src like `<content src="http://remoteserver.com/app/index.html">` the whitelist rules dont matter; cross origin requests are still blocked by chrome.